# is there a construct in catch2 to express a mapping of inputs vs. expected values?

Tags: c++, catch2

I have a set of **inputs** and their corresponding **expected outputs** for a function.

The test is currently written as follows:

```cpp
TEST_CASE("test reverse_and_double")
{
    struct { string input, string expected_output } tests[] = {
        { "abcd", "dcba" },
        { "hello", "olleh" },
        //...
    };

    for(auto &t : tests) {
        string output = my_reverse(t.input);  // function under test
        REQUIRE(output.size() == t.expected_output.size())
        CHECK(std::equal(output.begin(), output.end(), t.expected_output.begin()));
        //... many lines of CHECK & REQUIRE here...
    }
}
```

Now, in theory, unit-tests should not have (complex) mechanisms in order to be readable.
`GENERATE()` is the way Catch offers in order to use the same CHECKs for different inputs.
So, I tried it  and I removed the `for`loop:

```cpp
TEST_CASE("test reverse_and_double")
{
    struct { string input, string expected_output } t = GENERATE(
        { "abcd", "dcba" },
        { "hello", "olleh" },
        //...
    );

    string output = my_reverse(t.input);  // function under test
    REQUIRE(output.size() == t.expected_output.size())
    CHECK(std::equal(output.begin(), output.end(), t.expected_output.begin()));
    //... many lines of CHECK & REQUIRE here...
    }
}
```

However, there still is a 'mechanism' buried in the `struct` of inputs vs expected outputs. Many people will have different ways of writing this.
I suppose this is a common pattern in unit-tests.
**Does Catch offer a build-in construct to express such situations in a consistent way?**

Comment: My unit test rule is:  arrange, act, assert.  No loops.  No if/switch.  What you are looking for is called a **parameterized test** (or closely related **data generators**), which means the test runner feeds data to the test which does the simple arrange, act, assert.  That's Catch2 feature request [850](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/850).  I am a fan of Catch2, but I've moved to Doctest, wherein you can do [parameterized tests](https://github.com/doctest/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/parameterized-tests.md).

Comment: Why not simply `REQUIRE(output == t.expected_output)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, you are right -- I just wanted to show that there are lots of CHECK/REQUIRE calls. Sorry!

Comment: You can provide MCVE using this: https://godbolt.org/z/8GEGTK6TM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but [documentation](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/generators.md) lacks off good examples, in this case you need feed `table<...>` generator to `GENERATE` macro:

```cpp
std::string my_reverse(std::string_view s)
{
    return {s.rbegin(), s.rend()};
}

TEST_CASE("test reverse_and_double")
{
    auto [input, expected_output] = GENERATE(table<std::string, std::string>({
        { "abcd", "dcba" },
        { "hello", "olleh" },
    }));

    CAPTURE(input);
    REQUIRE(my_reverse(input) == expected_output);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GbrPxdbrb

I had problems understanding documentation and had to inspect unit test and other projects source code on github to fill gaps.

Note I used `CAPTURE` so it is clear which argument was used when test fails.

Comment: when do I need to explicitly construct a `table` ? I am pretty sure that you don't always have to...

Comment: @GrimFandango `table` is just one of generators. There are other generators you can use there. With `from_range` you can use ranges form C++20 or library which are lazy evaluated. There is `map` generator which you can feed function which will provide a data.